# Construtor cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java

I uploaded my project to the server and found an error. The program runs okay, even with the error.
I am confused and want to know why. The `Testable` is an interface and I cannot add a constructor to it.

The `NimPlayer` is an abstract class.

Any help is appreciated.

```
Tester.java:12: error: constructor NimAIPlayer in class NimAIPlayer cannot be applied to given types;
        Testable player = new NimAIPlayer();
                          ^
required: String,String,String
found: no arguments
```

Here is the `Testable` interface:

```
public interface Testable {
    public String advancedMove(boolean[] available, String lastMove);
}
```

Here is part of `NimPlayer` abstract class:

```
abstract class NimPlayer extends Nimsys implements Serializable  {

    private String userName;
    private String familyName;
    private String givenName;
    private int gamesPlayed;
    private int gamesWon;

   public NimPlayer(String userName, String familyName, String givenName) {

        this.userName = userName;
        this.familyName = familyName;
        this.givenName = givenName;
        this.gamesPlayed = 0;
        this.gamesWon = 0;
    }
    // getters and setters
}
```

EDIT

Here is the `NimAIPlayer`:

```
public class NimAIPlayer extends NimPlayer implements Testable{

    private int stoneTaken;

    public int moveStone(int initialStone, int upperBound, int stoneBalance) {

        if (stoneBalance != 1) {
            stoneTaken = (stoneBalance - 1) % (upperBound + 1);
            return stoneTaken;
        } else {
            stoneTaken = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, upperBound + 1);
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public NimAIPlayer(String userName, String familyName, String givenName) {
        super(userName, familyName, givenName);//pass the NimAIPlayer to the parent class
    }

    public String advancedMove(boolean[] available, String lastMove) {
        // the implementation of the victory
        // guaranteed strategy designed by you
        String move = "";

        return move;
    }   
}
```

EDIT 2

NOW I KNOW WHAT DEFAULT CONSTRUCTORS DO.
Create a default constructor in both `NimAIPlayer` and abstract `NimPlayer` class . And put `super()` in subclass, which is `NimAIPlayer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When ever you have parameterized constructor in your class  , it's mandatory to have default constuctor defined** . When you do not have any parameterized constructor , at that time default constructor is provided by JVM .

Add default constructor as below

```
abstract class NimPlayer extends Nimsys implements Serializable  {

private String userName;
private String familyName;
private String givenName;
private int gamesPlayed;
private int gamesWon;

public NimPlayer(){
 }

public NimPlayer(String userName, String familyName, String givenName) {

    this.userName = userName;
    this.familyName = familyName;
    this.givenName = givenName;
    this.gamesPlayed = 0;
    this.gamesWon = 0;
}
// getters and setters
}
```

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Could you please explain?

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you declared a constructor with multiple arguments, you must also provide a default no-arg constructor if you intend to call it:

```
public NimPlayer(){
    super();
}
```

Comment: And it would appear that OP is submitting the program to a testing environment which requires that a no-arg constructor be available.